# Value cannot be null ( parameter envolope)

Tags: azureservicebus, masstransit

I am trying to push messages to Topic from a .NET application, the messages are goes to dead letter queue and when I investigate the error message says Value cannot be null (parameter envelope)

But the same code works for another Topic, believe need to do any configuration in Topic it self.

[image]

Comment: This appears to be something related to Mass Transit, not Service Bus.  There is no concept of an `envelope` in Service Bus and those properties are non-standard and appear to be injected by Mass Transit.  The error message also indicates a serialization problem in Mass Transit.    I've retagged with `masstransit` so that the folks best able to assist can find this more easily.

Comment: MassTransit [Serialization](https://masstransit.io/documentation/configuration/serialization) - if you're posting raw JSON, you'll need to use raw JSON.